# Getting error with Scikits-Learn RandonForest trained in 64bit and opening in 64bit PyCharm

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I created a RandomForestClassifier model in Jupyter Notebook 64bit. I pickled it to load it into PyCharm 64bit and I am getting the following error when trying to run my python program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Justin/Desktop/C964/Thyroid_DX_PC/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    clf_model = pickle.load(open("clf_model.pkl", "rb"))
  File "sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx", line 607, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.__cinit__
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'SIZE_t' but got 'long long'
```

I can confirm that Jupyter and PyCharm are both running 64bit Python. The only cause for this error I can find online is this mismatch so I am completely lost. Thanks!

Comment: Are the Jupyter Notebook and PyCharm using the same versions of Python?  What does `import ctypes ; print (ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp))` show in each?

Comment: Jupyter notebook output is 8 and PyCharm is 4. Juptyer Notebook is running Python 3.8.5. I just did a fresh download of Pycharm. My interpreter is set to Python 3.7. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

While my Conda/Jupyter Notebook and PyCharm were 64-bit, my python was not 64-bit. It was 32-bit. I upgraded to 64-bit and the situation was resolved.